# List customers who haven't ordered any products that another one has

Tags: mysql, sql

These three tables are part of a larger order management system:

```
 orders
o_id c_id
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    5


order_items
o_id  p_id
1     1
2     2
3     1
3     2
3     8
4     1
4     2
5     8
5     9
6     4
6     5
7    12

customers
c_id   name
1     Doug
2     Tammy
3     Bill
4     Don
5     Kate
```

I want to find ALL pairs of customers where the second customer in the pair has purchased NONE of the products that the first customer in the pair has purchased. I can't seem to figure this out! My best attempt was grabbing the count of all unique products and trying to see if I could group and reduce by leveraging that count.

```
Expected Output
c_id1  c_id2
 4      1
 4      2
 4      3
 4      5
 5      1
 5      2
 5      3
```

Or the exact opposite (no duplicates).

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  o_id      INT,
  c_id      INT
);

INSERT INTO orders (o_id, c_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 2), 
(4, 3),
(5, 3),
(6, 4),
(7, 5);

CREATE TABLE order_items (
  o_id      INT,
  p_id      INT
);

INSERT INTO order_items (o_id, p_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 1), 
(3, 2),
(3, 8),
(4, 1),
(4, 2),
(5, 8),
(5, 9),
(6, 4),
(6, 5),
(7, 12);

CREATE TABLE customers (
  c_id      INT,
  name      VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO customers (c_id, name) VALUES
(1, 'Doug'),
(2, 'Tammy'),
(3, 'Bill'), 
(4, 'Don'),
(5, 'Kate');
```

Comment: The example dataset is bit confusing becasue the customers 6 and 7 are not in customers and also in the orders

Comment: @Fact Whoops. Fixed

Comment: @Akina Added scripts

Answer (score 0):

Test

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *
              FROM orders
              NATURAL JOIN order_items
              NATURAL JOIN customers )
SELECT t1.c_id id1, t2.c_id id2
FROM customers t1
JOIN customers t2 ON t1.c_id < t2.c_id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM cte cte1, cte cte2
                   WHERE cte1.c_id = t1.c_id
                     AND cte2.c_id = t2.c_id
                     AND cte1.p_id = cte2.p_id );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=034047ea113c4df0ae56d36918800dcf)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to generate all pairs of customers (using a `cross join`).

Then check that they do not have the same items.  This is a little tricky, but it involves `not exists` and joining down to the item level to see if any match on orders that match the customers:

```
select c1.c_id, c2.c_id
from customers c1 cross join
     customers c2
where not exists (select 1
                  from order_items oi1 join
                       order_items oi2
                       on oi1.i_id = oi2.i_id join
                       orders o1
                       on o1.o_id = oi1.o_id join
                       orders o2
                       on o2.o_id = oi2.o_id
                  where o1.c_id = c1.c_id and
                        o2.c_id = o2.c_id
                 );
```